# MySQL stopping in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I try to run my MySQL from the XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.1, but it stops a bit after I hit Start. It says it's running for a solid second, then crashes. I tried changing its ports, but didn't work.

Here's what it said in the control panel:

> 8:08:18 PM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 8:08:18 PM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>
> 8:08:18 PM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>
> 8:08:18 PM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>
> 8:08:18 PM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 8:08:18 PM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 8:08:18 PM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums

Answer (score -1):

Go to Task Manager, see the services regarding mysqls and stop them as administrator and then try, it will connect.

If it doesn't work then try this command in your cmd:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

Comment: Please share more details. Usually, `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin` won't work on a Windows system